# How to insert text of an input into another input when typing using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, input

I have two textbox.I want to copy the text in key press event fron one textbox to another in jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".first").keydown(function() {
    $(".second").value($(".first").value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Enter your name:
<input type="text" class="first">
<input type="text" class="second">
```

Comment: Closing as a typo. The method is `val()`, not `value`. Please familiarise yourself with the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/val

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In jQuery you want to use the `val` function and not the value property.
2. You should use `keyup` event instead of `keydown` to copy correctly

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".first").keyup(function(){
        $(".second").val($(".first").val());
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Enter your name: <input type="text" class="first">
<input type="text" class="second">
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".first").keydown(function(){
        $(".second").val($(".first").val());
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Enter your name: <input type="text" class="first">
<input type="text" class="second">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is right but jquery hasn't `.value()` method. You should use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead.

```
$(".first").keydown(function(){
  $(".second").val($(this).val());
  // or
  $(".second").val(this.value);
});
```

```js
$(".first").keydown(function(){
  $(".second").val($(".first").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your name: 
<input type="text" class="first">
<input type="text" class="second">
```

Also to better performance, add `keyup` and `change` event to element. The [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is good method to adding multiple event to element.

```
$(".first").on("keydown keyup change", function(){
  $(".second").val(this.value);
});
```

```js
$(".first").on("keydown keyup change", function(){
  $(".second").val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your name: 
<input type="text" class="first">
<input type="text" class="second">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's 'val' method here to achieve this.

I would also recommend using jQuery's 'keyup' instead of 'keydown'. If you do it on keydown you will always be one letter behind.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".first").keyup(function() {
    $(".second").val($(".first").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your name:
<input type="text" class="first">
<input type="text" class="second">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$(".first").keydown(function(){
    $(".second").val($(".first").val());
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".first").keyup(function() {
    $(".second").val($(".first").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Enter your name: <input type="text" class="first">
<input type="text" class="second">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".second").click(function(){
        $(".second").val($(".first").val());
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Enter your name: <input type="text" class="first">
<input type="text" class="second">
```